# How to get the git commit differences between branches

Tags: git

I am missing some commits that are in my dev branch but not in master.  Some commits were merged in, some were not.

I can get the difference between the branches by doing something like:

```
git diff master..develope
git diff --name-status master..branch
git diff --stat --color master..branchName
```

However, this give me the file difference. 
I want to know if there anyway I could get the actual git commits rather than the file differences?

Comment: if this is a local branch you can also try a `git rebase master`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one of the uses for `git cherry` (note: not `git cherry-pick`). You would use it this way:

```
git checkout master
git cherry dev
```

This will identify the commits in `dev` for which the equivalent changes have not been introduced in `master`. Note that this does more than just looking at commit hashes, since a cherry-picked commit will introduce the same changes, but will have a different parent and commit date, and possibly different committer, so the hash will be different. `git cherry` tries to identify the "cherries" that could be picked but haven't been yet...

Answer (score 2):

To see the commits that are in develope but not in master:

```
git log master..develope
```

This syntax literally means "print out the develope log minus the master log".

Note that this only shows commits from develope that aren't in master.  To see the converse, commits in master that aren't in develope, just invert the args:

```
git log develope..master
```

Answer (score 1):

I think `git log master..develop` is what you want.

This is a pretty cool command too - it'll show you visually how they differ:

`git log --graph --pretty=format:'%Cred%h%Creset -%C(yellow)%d%Creset %s %Cgreen(%cr)%Creset' --abbrev-commit --date=relative master develop`